# escape `|' in \verb

Tags: latex

In LaTex, if I use **\verb**, how can I escape `|`? For example, I want to display `ab|bc`: \verb|ab`[]`bc|. What should replace `[]`?

Comment: Did you know there's a Tex/LaTex SE site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ? They may get you a quicker answer.

Comment: Now I know. Thank you for the info :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use other characters in `\verb` than `|`; for example, you can do `\verb!ab|bc!` to allow you to use `|` in your string.