# Pipe character in MathJax verb block

Tags: mathjax

I'd like to insert a code with pipe (|) char in it as a verb block of MathJax.

I could insert a code using MathJax in the following way:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js"></script>
\(
    \verb|int foo(void)| \\
    \verb|{| \\
    \verb|    echo "test is ok!";| \\    
    \verb|}| \\
\)
```

But is there any way to insert pipe char in it to print "test is | ok!"? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937440/escape-in-verb#4937557 (which works in MathJax as well)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.